# how to fix compatibility warning after updating tagentry plugin for dokuwiki

Tags: plugins, compatibility, dokuwiki

My task is to update the dokuwiki. When I started i had two warnings that the tag and the **tagentry** plugins are not compatible.

(e. g. "Warning: Declaration of action_plugin_tagentry::register(&$controller) should be compatible with DokuWiki_Action_Plugin::register(Doku_Event_Handler $controller) in ...\lib\plugins\tagentry\action.php on line 300")

With downloading and replacing the action.php for the tag plugin the warning for it went away. Doing the same with the Tagentry plugin doesn't remove the warning. When I open this action.php the line 300 is just the closing curly bracket. What steps do I need to take to remove this warning?

Emptying the cache doesn't work.